# Python to Mips Pattern conversion

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, mips

My school assignment requires me to convert this python code to mips, I am beginner at MIPS hence I have no idea how to approach this solution.

Please make sure to comment the code which could help me understand the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA.

#Set Values

#take input for max no of symbols from user

max_no_of_symbols=int(input("Enter Max Number Of Sybols(should Be ODD)"))

#only enter odd num

if max_no_of_symbols %2 == 0:

```
print("Error, Please enter a odd number")
```

else:

```
#caculate num of spaces

NumOfSpaces=int((max_no_of_symbols-1)/2)

NumOfSymbols=1

while NumOfSymbols != max_no_of_symbols :

    #print output

    for i in range(NumOfSpaces):

        print(" ",end="")

    for i in range(NumOfSymbols):

        print(NumOfSymbols, end="")

    #adjusting values for new line

    NumOfSpaces=NumOfSpaces-1

    NumOfSymbols=NumOfSymbols+2

    print(" ")


while NumOfSymbols != 0 :

   #print output

    for i in range(NumOfSpaces):

        print(" ",end="")

    for i in range(NumOfSymbols):

        print(NumOfSymbols, end="")

    #adjusting values for new line

    NumOfSpaces=NumOfSpaces+1

    NumOfSymbols=NumOfSymbols-2

    print(" ")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, your question isn't really answerable, shy of someone writing an entire program for you. Since StackOverflow is not a code writing service, these questions are considered off topic. After reading the links above, please edit your question to include your attempts so far, and what precise problem you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

As youre begginer this link might help you in learning basic concepts of mips:

[https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~dszajda/classes/cs301/Fall_2020/labs/MIPS_assembly_language_using_QTSpim.pdf](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/%7Edszajda/classes/cs301/Fall_2020/labs/MIPS_assembly_language_using_QTSpim.pdf)

Also I have tried my best to convert your code to MIPS, also heavily commented the code which will help you understand, as you requested.

Happy Learning :)

.data

```
Prompt: .asciiz "Enter value of n: "

Blankspace: .asciiz " "

newLine: .asciiz "\n"
```

.text

.globl main

main:

```
#Input Value  for num variable

li $v0, 4

la $a0, Prompt

syscall

#Calculate the Max num of Symbols stored in T0

#Save Value from console to t0

li $v0, 5

syscall

move $t0, $v0

#Calculate No of spaces stored in T1

sub $t1, $t0, 1

div $t1, $t1, 2

#Num of symbols are stored in T2

#Initially in line 1 there is 1

li $t2, 1

j whileloop
```

.end main

##PRINTING TOP PYRAMID

whileloop:

```
#While NumOfSymbols != max_no_of_symbols

#if T2==T0 then jump to whileloop2(which prints bottom half of pyramid)

beq $t2, $t0, whileloop2

#t3 will loop to num of blankSpaces

li $t3, 0

#t4 will loop to NumOfSymbols

li $t4, 0

j forloop1
```

.end whileloop

forloop1:

```
#for t3 in rangenumOfSpaces

#break the loop if t3 equals t1

beq $t3, $t1 forloop2

li $v0, 4

la $a0, Blankspace

syscall

#incrementation of t3

addi $t3, $t3, 1

#jump to print another blank otherwise

j forloop1
```

.end forloop1

forloop2:

```
#for t4 in range numOfSymbols

#break the loop if t4 equals t2

#and jump to adjust values for new num of symbols and spaces

beq $t4, $t2 adjustValues

#making a copy of t2 for printing

addi $t5, $t2, 0

move $a0, $t5

li $v0, 1

syscall 

#incrementation of t4

addi $t4, $t4, 1

#jump to print another symbol otherwise

j forloop2
```

.end forloop2

adjustValues:

```
#Spaces Decrease

sub $t1, $t1, 1

#Symbols Increase

addi $t2, $t2, 2

li $v0, 4

la $a0, newLine

syscall 

j whileloop
```

.end adjustValues

##PRINTING BOTTOM PYRAMID

whileloop2:

```
#While NumOfSymbols != 0

#if T2==0 then jump to exit(which exits the program)

ble $t2, $zero, exit

#t3 will loop to num of blankSpaces

li $t3, 0

#t3 will loop to num of symbols

li $t4, 0

j forloop3
```

.end whileloop2

forloop3:

```
#for t3 in rangenumOfSpaces

#break the loop if t3 equals t1

beq $t3, $t1 forloop4

#Printing blank

li $v0, 4

la $a0, Blankspace

syscall

#incrementint t3

addi $t3, $t3, 1

#Jump to print new blank elsewise

j forloop3
```

.end forloop3

forloop4:

```
#for t4 in range numOfSymbols

beq $t4, $t2 adjustValues2

#break the loop if t5 equals t2

#and jump to adjust values for new num of symbols and spaces

addi $t5, $t2, 0

move $a0, $t5

li $v0, 1

syscall

#incrementint t4

addi $t4, $t4, 1

j forloop4
```

.end forloop4

adjustValues2:

```
#Spaces Increase

addi $t1, $t1, 1

#Symbols Decrease

sub $t2, $t2, 2

li $v0, 4

la $a0, newLine

syscall 

j whileloop2
```

.end adjustValues2

exit:

```
#Exiting the program

syscall 

li $v0,10

syscall
```

.end exit